# Print part of windows form with designated range?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

So I have been looking through the documentation for 
`System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument`
in visual studio, using c#. 
After hours of looking through I have not found a way to print part of a windows form.(from (x,y) to (x1,y1). An example would be print.Range(20,20,320,520), which would be the range of point (20,20) to point (320,520). 
The idea is I would like to be able to print part of the windows form. For example if there is an image I would like to be able to print that image and anything else that is on top of it, or around it. Is there a method or way of printing a range of pixels that I have not found? Or is there a work around to get this to work? Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Consult [... everything printed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6914545), [How to print entire form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31702101/)

Comment: I just found an excellent article: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/eb80fbbe-6b89-4c3d-9ede-88a2b105c714/how-to-print-windows-form-in-c-application
Also thanks @DourHighArch those are excellent resources.